# mongoid :trying to embed a document which is embedded in another document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I'm using sinatra and i want to embed a document using the realtion Embedded 1-1

this is my main collection that embeds just one environment
    class TestSuite
      include Mongoid::Document

```
 field :testSuiteName
 field :introduction
 field :itemsToTest
 field :dateCreation

 attr_accessible  :testSuiteName,:introduction,:itemsToTest,:dateCreation

 embeds_one :environment
 embeds_many :steps
end
```

every TestSuite embeds many steps

```
class Step
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :stepRole
 field :stepOrderNum

 embedded_in :testSuite
 embedded_in :environment
 has_one  :function
end
```

to run a testSuite i had to set the test environment that's embeds many steps

```
class Environment
 include Mongoid::Document

 embedded_in :testSuite
 embeds_many :steps 
end

get '/createTestSuite' do
 name=params[:testName]
 intro=params[:introduction]
 items=['data','shemas']


 test1=TestSuite.create()

 test1.testSuiteName="firstOne"
 test1. introduction="my first Test Suite"
 test1.itemsToTest=["data","shemas"]
 test1. dateCreation="23/01/214 18:18"

 test1.environment.create()
 test1.environment.steps.create(stepRole: "inserer donneés",stepOrderNum:   "2")
```

the problem :

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass:
C:/Users/mohamedamine.sakhri/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/zProject/main.rb:99:in `block in <main>'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `block in compile!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `[]'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:985:in `route_eval'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1006:in `block in process_route'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `catch'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `process_route'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:964:in `block in route!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `each'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `route!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `block in dispatch!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `dispatch!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `block in call!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `call!'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:217:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:210:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2014:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `block in call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1788:in `synchronize'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `call'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

how could i do to create a testSuite withe an environment document embedded ?

Comment: Is it valid to have two `embedded_in`s in one `class Step`? Is there perhaps a `class Environment` from somewhere else that is conflicting with yours?

Comment: I don't know if it's valid to to have two embedded_ins in one class Step but when i delete the embeds_many :steps from the class Environment the same problem appears